# Cannot identify language in SALT

Tags: salt-stack

I just started using SALT for a project i am working on. It is said to work with Python but I find quite a bit of difference in thier syntax and overall format. I have pasted a code for a simple task which just opens and imports and loads some libraries onto the SALT console. I hope someone can check abnd see if he/she can instantly identify the language being used and what the code does. This is because i have a suspicion that the code is a mixture between C, Python as well as Java... if that is so doen't that mean it should be a totally different language on its own?

code:

```
var rtwxlib = import'rtwxlib';
var string = import'string';

var monitor = rtwxlib.Monitor
{
    EvActivate = func() { print "Activate\n"; };
    EvShutdown = func() { print "Shutdown\n"; };
    EvProgress = func(self, fDone, msg = "") { 
        print("Progress: %d %s                                          \r"::format(fDone*100, msg));
    };
    EvEventMsg = func(self, msg) { 
        print("\nEvent: %s\n"::format(iStat, msg));
    };
};

var solver = rtwxlib.Solver(monitor);

solver::Open("test.wrx");
solver::DelGeometry();

solver::SaveAs('testresults.wrx');
solver::Close();
```

Comment: Could you provide the link for the source of this code so we can answer more accurately?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to indentify the syntax of the language used as C. I beieve the problem I had which confused me was the libraries used for this code which I later found out was for a particular program. Thank you to all those who tried to help though :)